# AngularJS: submit() doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, element, form-submit

Issuing a `submit()` command to an element just refreshes the page instead of going to the form's action attribute:

```
<form action="somepage.html" id="myform">
</form>
...
angular.element('#myform').submit();
```

I tried a workaround that works by creating a hidden submit button and triggering a click event to it:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="hidden"> 
... 
angular.element('#submit').click();
```

I totally disdain the idea that we have to create a new directive just to accomplish such simple task.

Any ideas if this is possible without creating another directive?

Thank you.

Comment: weird. so, submitting a form, did what submitting a form should do?

Comment: What did you expect clicking the submit button or submitting the form to do? What isn't working?

Comment: Don't try to use angular like it's jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this button is already in a controller or directive scope.

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="hidden">
```

So, change it to

```
<button type="button" id="submit" ng-click="doSave()" class="hidden">Save</button>
```

and in your controller (or directive) add method

```
$scope.doSave function()  {...}
```

Comment: Yeah, just as I was  trying to void. I guess it's the only way to go then. Really appreciate it though. +1